# How to use nextPartitionKey and nextRowKey in vb6.0 when reading data in azure table?

Tags: azure, vb6

I use the following code to read data from azure table.
The first time in URL2 I send only `mark=0`.

Reading the first data, I read the values of `nextPartitionKey` and `nextRowKey` to include them into `URL2` in order
to read next data from next partition since I can only read 1000 items at a time.

Using `URL2` the second time with the values of `nextPartitionKey` and `nextRowKey`, the program reads the same data as in the first partition. In some way it gets stuck.

Can someone see what is wrong in the following code please?

```
    URL2 = "https://data1-dev.azure-api.net/ReadInfo?mark=0" 
    Set XMLServer = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Set XMLReceive = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    XMLServer.SetTimeouts 5000, 60000, 10000, 10000
    XMLServer.Option(9) = 2048
    XMLServer.Option(6) = True
    
    Do
       XMLServer.Open "GET", URL2, False
       
       XMLServer.SetRequestHeader "ID_number", UserID
       XMLServer.SetRequestHeader "Key", UserKey
       XMLServer.Send ""
       ResultText = XMLServer.ResponseText
       
       'I read here the values of nextPartitionKey and  nextRowKey from 
       'ResultText and I save 
       'them into stNextPartiotionKey and stNextRowKey variables

       URL2 = "https://data1-dev.azure-api.net/ReadInfo?Mark=0 & 
       NextPartitionKey=" & 
       stNextPartiotionKey & " & NextRowKey=" & stNextRowKey     

    Loop While stNextPartiotionKey <> "" And stNextRowKey <> ""
```

Comment: What is this URL - `https://data1-dev.azure-api.net/ReadInfo?mark=0`? This is not the endpoint for table storage.

Comment: This is an example of URL but the real one is an endpoint table storage.

Comment: Can you help me by telling me what is wrong in my code please to be able to read data from next partition since I get the values of Nextpartitionkey and nextRowKey ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Azure Table API, but this URL...

```
URL2 = "https://data1-dev.azure-api.net/ReadInfo?Mark=0 & NextPartitionKey=" & 
       stNextPartiotionKey & " & NextRowKey=" & stNextRowKey
```

...doesn't look right. Assuming it's not a copy&paste error, you need to remove the spaces around the "&" sign:

```
URL2 = "https://data1-dev.azure-api.net/ReadInfo?Mark=0&NextPartitionKey=" & 
       stNextPartiotionKey & "&NextRowKey=" & stNextRowKey
```

Generally speaking, spaces in URLs are **never** valid*). If there actually *is* a space in an URL, it needs to be encoded, e.g. `https://my space url` needs to be encoded like `https://my%20space%20url`.

*) I blame Internet Explorer for people tricking into believing it *is* valid, as it accepted those URLs and showed them in the address bar "as is", but secretly encoded them when sending. Take Firefox on the other hand, which converts spaces in URLs visibly in the address bar to `%20`

Comment: I changed it to :             URL2 = "https://mydata-dev.azure-api.net/RequestTransmittedDocs?Mark=0&NextPartitionKey=" & stNextPartiotionKey & "NextRowKey=" & stNextRowKey     If I remove the spaces before and after the &, I get a syntax error from VB6.0. I don't know why but when this command is executed, it is adding a space right after the equal sign. For example it is writing NextRowKey= 1!20.....   and I cannot see how I can correct this

Comment: It should be saved as NextRowKey=1!20..... (without a space before 1!20...

Comment: I'd check your variables (stNextRowKey) then. Most likely it includes a leading spaces. Also: don't mistake VB's string concatenation operator  `&` for the string literal `"&"` in the URL. VB requires a space there, e.g. `strVar & "literal string"`. But the _resulting_ URL should not have _any_ spaces in it.

Comment: Finally it worked ! Thank you very much for your help.I changed the URL2 to             URL2 = "https://mydata-dev.azure-api.net/RequestTransmittedDocs?Mark=0&NextPartitionKey=" & stNextPartiotionKey & "&NextRowKey=" & stNextRowKey   and it worked.
I wish you to have a very nice day !. All the best to you !

Comment: If it worked, you might want to consider marking the aswer as "accepted" _(IMHO that's waht it's called)_ so that others with similar problems have an easier job of finding it.